# ANTLR4 -no viable alternative at input 's4'

Tags: java, eclipse, calculator, antlr4, lang

I have to make a calculator  in Java using AntLR .But when i try to calculate the square root using the command s 4 it shows me :no viable alternative at input 's4'.
I really need your help for this. I try everything and I dont know whats is wrong.
This is my grammar:

```
grammar Hello;

r  : r SEMI r EOF
   | r SEMI
   | plus_op
   | minus_op
   | sqrt_op;

   // match keyword hello followed by an identifier

   ID : [a-z]+ ;             // match lower-case identifiers

   NUM : [0-9];

   WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ; // skip spaces, tabs, newlines

   ADD : '+';

   MINUS : '-';

   SEMI: ';';

  SQRT: 's';

  plus_token: NUM | ID;

  minus_token: NUM | ID;

 sqrt_token: NUM;

 plus_op :  plus_token ADD plus_token;  

 minus_op : minus_token MINUS minus_token;

sqrt_op: SQRT sqrt_token;
```

Comment: `s 4` can be both, `ID NUM` and `SQRT NUM`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/35630746/6505250

Answer (score 0):

`SQRT` will never be matched as `ID` matches the same input. This is because ANTLR won't try to match the input with multiple rules in the lexer but rather uses the first found rule that can match the current input.

The problem should be solved if `SQRT` is being defined before `ID` in the grammar.